# Colour around iPhone Notch in Cordova/Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I have developed a iPhone app using Cordova however I end up with a white area around the iPhone Notch that would like to fill blue to match the top menu.

[image]

I would have thought this would be easy but so far I have not found a nice solution.

I know that I could set `viewport-fit=cover` But this would mean my menubar etc would go behind the iPhone status icons etc

Comment: I think can set background-color on the .html class in your css

Comment: You can set the color of statusbar using [statusbar plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/index.html#statusbarbackgroundcolorbyhexstring)